# 301 error and sample test

Tags: c#, asp.net, error-handling

how to test 301 error in local host in asp.net.I add global.asax page and written a code

```
 void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         const string www = "http://www.localhost/test";
         const string redirect = "http://localhost/test/";
         string request = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString();

         if (request.StartsWith(www, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
         {
             HttpContext.Current.Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
             HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Location",
               redirect + request.Substring(www.Length));
         }
     }
```

and configure localhost through virtual directory but i m not able to see any change as my configure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use [`HttpResponse.RedirectPermanent()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd384856.aspx) instead? It's built in:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.RedirectPermanent(redirectUrl);
```